# Magento Order Email not sending randomly

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an issue where order emails are not being send at the same time and also some emails are skipped. I did check in core_email_queue and core_email_queue_recipients and found there are 10 records in first table and for those orders customer and admin did not receive any email for. How do i process this queue emails and what should i do to make sure this should not happen in future ? 
I did check with the cron and its working fine and setup to run every 5 minute.

Does SMTP Pro free extension replace this default Magento email queue process and fix the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After Magento 1.9 the order confirmation emails are not sent during checkout anymore and instead are being sent with the cron. Make sure your Cron is working (you can check the cron logs `/var/log/cron`).

Also make sure Magento cron is running every five minutes. You should see something like this in Crontab (in your server):

```
*/5 * * * * /public_html/cron.sh
```

this extension helps you to manage cron jobs in Magento: [AOE Scheduler](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html)

**OR**

Just do a small change in `order.php (public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php)`   (Don't forget to override this one)

From

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

To

```
$mailer->send();
```

**OR**

Another Solution:

```
go to System -> Configuration -> ASCHRODER EXTENSIONS -> SMTP -> Queue Configuration -> Queue Usage -> Never
```

Comment: In my Megento experience, this is the best solution. There is absolutely no need for a mail queue in Magento 1.x given it uses sendmail and sendmail manages a queue itself and is usually hosted on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Magento 1.9.1 the emails are not being sent directly during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via Magento cronjob.

There is no problem with Magento cronjobs. The command is correct. Email sent successfully. Even though receivers of the mail are not correct.

How does Magento determine the receivers of the mail? From table `core_email_queue_recipients` that has a relation with table `core_email_queue`.

MySQL supports foreign keys, which let you cross-reference related data across tables, and foreign key constraints, which help keep this spread-out data consistent.

Magento add a CONSTRAINT and FOREIGN KEY `message_id` to table `core_email_queue_recipients`.

ALTER TABLE `core_email_queue_recipients`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_6F4948F3ABF97DE12127EF14B140802A` FOREIGN KEY (`message_id`) REFERENCES `core_email_queue` (`message_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

FOREIGN KEY `message_id` will refer to `message_id` from table `core_email_queue`. Both tables are bound each other now. Table `core_email_queue` will be a parent and `core_email_queue_recipients` as a child. If I delete a row with `message_id` = 1 from `core_email_queue`. Every rows with `message_id` = 1 from `core_email_queue_recipients` will also be deleted by MySQL automatically.

So, what is the real problem? I log into MySQL database server. I find table `core_email_queue_recipients` does not have FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT. I do not know why. Perhaps, he or his developer ever remove the table. So, every time cronjobs clean up email queue. MySQL server only delete email queue. Email recipients of deleted queue are ignored. Data integrity of table `core_email_queue_recipients` is broken now.